# Table of contents formatting in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to add a simple table of contents to a word document, where the headings are numbered, but Word is formatting strangely – it is placing the header text on the line after the number, and formatting the first heading very wrong (right aligned). It appears the same way regardless of TOC style used.
The TOC:

[image: TOC]

A heading:

[image: Heading]

Styles pane:

[image: Styles pane]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **Tab settings** in your TOC *styles*. It looks to me as if you have a very small initial tab setting.

See [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill

If you want something more definitive, modify your question by including a link to a sample document showing this problem. (A short and perhaps purged excerpt from the problem document with your TOC and one or two headings should  be sufficient.)

Comment: I couldn't see anything in tab settings, but I did notice, as I had change tracking enabled, in changing some formatting it has tracked "Adjust space between Latin and Asian text, Adjust space between Asian text and numbers", I wondered if that had anything to do with it because the document is all English, no Asian text. Anyway, after copying everything into a new document the TOC is correct, so I've worked around the issue.

Comment: Good to hear. The TOC is  a field and Track Changes gives "interesting" results with fields. The setting may well have been the cause, though. Glad you worked it out. The copy into a new document is the Word equivalent for documents of a reboot.